# PIXI JS - I want to change Width/height and Position of Rectangle with Mouse

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

```
var rectangle = new Graphics();
        rectangle.beginFill(0, 0.001);
        rectangle.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
        rectangle.drawRect(5, 5, 200, 100);

        rectangle.interactive = true;
        rectangle.buttonMode = true;
        rectangle.on('pointerdown', onDragStart)
            .on('pointerup', onDragEnd)
            .on('pointerupoutside', onDragEnd)
            .on('pointermove', onDragMove);
        app.viewport.addChild(rectangle);
```

I'm using this code to create a rectangle and adding it to rectangle. This is the onDragMove Function

```
    function onDragMove() {
        if (this.dragging) {
            const newPosition = this.data.getLocalPosition(this.parent);
            this.width = newPosition.x;
            this.height = newPosition.y;
        
        }
    }
```

This is basically changing its width and height, but I also want to Drag the Rectangle when clicked inside the rectangle and dragged on the screen. Any suggestions how can I achieve this?

- Borders to change width/height
- clicking inside rectangle to drag on the screen.

Comment: Please look first at standard Pixi.js examples - here is about dragging: https://pixijs.io/examples/#/interaction/dragging.js

Comment: @domis86 Thank you, I had a look on it. But the problem is I want to change width/height of Graphics when clicked on its border and drag when move cursor is inside the graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created working example of dragging and resizing: https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/SbpTjm7WKXbL51kmiG89W - please check.

- when you click near bottom border of rectangle (+/- 20 px) then you will start resizing it.
- when you click in any other place inside rectangle then you will drag it

Basing on this example i think you can implement resizing of other borders of rectangle etc :)

One note: please look at function `drawRectangle` :

```
function drawRectangle(rectangle)
{
    rectangle.clear();
    rectangle.beginFill(0, 0.001);
    rectangle.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
    rectangle.drawRect(rectangle.myRectanglePosition[0], rectangle.myRectanglePosition[1], rectangle.myRectanglePosition[2], rectangle.myRectanglePosition[3]);
}
```

^ the `rectangle.clear();` is called to redraw the `PIXI.Graphics` object. So on each frame we clear and draw it again on specific position with specific width & height.

Comment: Thanks, That's really impressive and thank you for taking the creating a playground.

Comment: Is there a way to detect the border of the Circle? I want to increase the radius of the circle when dragged on border but I am not able to make the logic to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @mohsin yes - for this purpose you can utilise Pythagorean Distance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Two_dimensions - to know distance between mouse position and center of circle. In this playground i used it to calculate variable `distanceFromCenter` : https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/2Uh_-K39-aPECszRRJk0R